# C# WinForms key events not working when showing child control

Tags: c#, winforms, keyup

I have a form called "MainView" which holds a UserControl called "GameState" (I use a state machine). In the "GameState" UserControl I draw the game world. I also have a KeyUp event in "GameState" which will show the UserControl "InGameMenu" in the "GameState" UserControl (InGameMenu.visible = true) when Escape is pressed.

When I press Escape the menu shows. If I press Escape again the menu hides again. After the menu is clicked I can't get the key events from "GameState" and "InGameMenu" working again though. First I thought it was a simple focusing issue, so I tried clicking "GameState" and "InGameMenu" to check if that made the key events work, but it didn't. I also tried adding the key event from "GameState" to the "InGameMenu" event handler or handling the key events in the "InGameMenu", but that didn't work either (neither is fired). I have a close button on the "InGameMenu". When I click that the menu hides and the key events from "GameState" work again.

Why aren't the key events from "GameState" and "InGameMenu" firing when "InGameMenu" is open?

Thanks in advance.

**GameState Code**

```
public partial class GameState : UserControl, IState<MainView>
{
    private bool ready = false;
    private Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
    private SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    private InGameMenu menu;

    public GameState()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.menu = new InGameMenu();
        this.menu.Location = new Point(this.Width / 2 - menu.Width / 2, this.Height / 2 - menu.Height / 2);
        this.menu.Visible = false;
        this.addControl(this.menu);      
    }

    public void addControl(Control control)
    {
        control.KeyUp += this.GameState_KeyUp;
        this.Controls.Add(control);
    }

    public void enter(MainView owner)
    {
        this.Width = owner.Width;
        this.Height = owner.Height;
        this.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        owner.Controls.Add(this);
        World.getInstance().createWorld();
        this.Focus();    

        this.ready = true;
    }

    public void update(MainView owner)
    {
        //game stuff
        if (this.menu.Visible == false)
        {
            //game stuff
        }
        else
        {
            switch (this.menu.action)
            {
                case action.stop:
                    owner.stateMachine.setCurrentState(new MainMenuState());
                    break;
                case action.close:
                    this.menu.Visible = false;
                    this.Focus();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            this.menu.action = action.nothing;
        }      

    }

    private void GameState_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            if (this.menu.Visible == false)
            {
                this.menu.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                this.menu.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**InGameMenu Code**

```
namespace LordsAndLands.States.GameStateStuff
{
public enum action
{
    nothing,
    stop,
    close
}

public partial class InGameMenu : UserControl
{
    public action action = action.nothing;

    public InGameMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    private void buttonExitToMainMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.action = action.stop;
    }

    private void buttonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.action = action.close;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Keyboard events are raised on the control that has the focus.  UserControl really, *really* does not like to get the focus (it has no way to indicate it) and does everything it can to pass focus to one of its client controls.  It cannot do so when it doesn't have any yet.  But that got fixed when you called this.Controls.Add().  Override ProcessCmdKey() to see shortcut keystrokes before the control with the focus sees them.

Comment: I have overridden ProcessCmdKey and am handling key events in there now. Is that what you mean? It seems like a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Form.KeyPreview=true;` property of the Form and check in the Form event which key is press and what other controls should do.

The `KeyPreview` property:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the form will receive key events before the event is passed to the control that has focus.

More on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx).

Comment: I'm not handling the key events in the form, but in the UserControl "GameState" which is a control of the form "MainView"